# Postman Response OK, but on Alamofire return failure on Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I used GoogleMap Direction API to draw multiple location's route. I use postman to check response status, and I can check 200 OK. but problem is when I use Alamofire, response is Failure!

when I draw from origin to destination, response is ok.(always)
but if I add additional location, Alamofire return is failure.

Someone has same problem and to solve it?

[image]

[image]

below is my code. Thanx!

```
 originAddress = locationInfoList[0]
        destinationAddress = locationInfoList.last
        var wayPointUrl:String = ""
        var waypoint = locationInfoList.dropFirst()
        waypoint = waypoint.dropLast()

        for coordinate in waypoint {
            print("~~~~")

            let wayPoint = "|\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)"
            wayPointUrl.append(wayPoint)
            print("~XXXXXXX~~~")
            print(wayPointUrl)
            print("XXXXXXX")
        }

        directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
            "origin=\(originAddress.latitude),\(originAddress.longitude)&destination=\(destinationAddress.latitude),\(destinationAddress.longitude)&waypoints=optimize:true\(wayPointUrl)" +
        "&key=apikey"

        print("VVVVVVV")
        print(directionURL)
        print("VVVVVVVV")
    }

    Alamofire.request(directionURL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        print(response)

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            print(JSON)

            let mapResponse: [String: AnyObject] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject]

            let routesArray = (mapResponse["routes"] as? Array) ?? []

            let routes = (routesArray.first as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) ?? [:]

            let overviewPolyline = (routes["overview_polyline"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) ?? [:]
            let polypoints = (overviewPolyline["points"] as? String) ?? ""
            let line  = polypoints

            self.addPolyLine(encodedString: line)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that you need to escape some characters in the URL.

Comment: as @Larme says its seems to be problem in URL encoding

Comment: Please include in your question the code you use in the Alamofire network request.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I update my code, thanks!

Comment: @iGenio in Swift3, I only can find Failure message..

Comment: @SeongChanKang I would advise you to immediately invalidate your API key, since you just posted it on a public page...I have removed it from the question, but it will still be visible in the edit history.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for save my Privacy..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are sending the parameters in the URL and using JSON encoding. Change `JSONEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.default`for the encoding parameter of Alamofire request.

Also from the Google Map API Docs, It says as follows. So I believe, URL encoding will solve your issue.

*Each waypoint can be either a place name, address, or comma-separated latitude/longitude coordinates. Strings should be URL-escaped, so waypoints such as "Berlin,Germany|Paris,France" should be converted to Berlin%2CGermany%7CParis%2CFrance.*